# How do I randomly arrange elements?

Tags: r, function

I'm in the process of creating a memory game using the R console for a specified grid dimension (`n_row` , `n_col`). I want to arrange cards randomly on the playing field (invisible for players). Each pair of equal cards should correspond to a unique combination of symbol (`pch`) and color (`col`). How can I do this?

Here is my current code:

```
memory <- function(n_row = 6, n_col = 6, pch = 1:13, col = 1:8, n_player = 2) {

 # Select starting player
 player <- sample(1:n_player, 1, replace = TRUE) 

 # Print starting message
 cat(paste0("Player", player, "starts!"))
 cat(paste0("In each move you have to choose two cards."))

 # Stop function if n is odd
 n <- n_row * n_col
 if(n %% 2 != 0) 
   stop("Error in memory(): n_row * n_col must be an even number.")

 # Otherwise arrange cards randomly

}
```

Comment: R isn't really about arranging cards randomly on playing fields :) Perhaps you could formulate the problem in more technical terms, like constructing a dataframe with random entries or shuffling the elements of a vector

Comment: A few pointers: You could sample from all possible combinations of `pch` and `col`, e.g. like this: `x <- setNames(expand.grid(pch, col), c("pch", "col")); x[sample(seq_len(nrow(x)), n_row*n_col*.5), ]`, then use `rep` to repeat your picks at some point to have pairs.

Comment: @user12728748 Thanks, I'll take a closer look. How would you mark the symbols in the gird?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer the question of how you could mark the symbols:

```r
n_row = 6
n_col = 6
pch = 1:13
col = 1:8

x <- setNames(expand.grid(pch, col), c("pch", "col"))
x2 <- x[sample(seq_len(nrow(x)), n_row*n_col*.5), ]
x2 <- rbind(x2, x2)[sample(seq_len(n_row*n_col)), ]

# Plot
plot(NULL, xlim=c(0, n_col), ylim=c(0, n_row), axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
box(lwd = 2)
abline(h=seq(0, n_row), lty="dashed")
abline(v=seq(0, n_col), lty="dashed")
points(0.5 + (1:(n_row*n_col) %% n_col), 0.5 + (0:((n_row*n_col) -1) %/% n_col), 
    pch=x2$pch, col=x2$col, cex=3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: How can I make sure that by default the playfield is not visible to the players and a symbol is displayed only when the corresponding cell is called by a player?

Answer (score 0):

R is a statistical programming language, dice rolling and card games are its strengths ;-). They can naturally be represented with vectors and matrices. Let's assume each card has an integer code, e.g. 1 to 12, then we just need to mix them and then re-format it as matrix:

```r
## twelve pairs of cards
cards <- rep(1:12, each=2)

## mix the cards
mixed <- sample(cards)

## arrange it at a gameboard
gameboard <- matrix(mixed, nrow=4, ncol=6)

## show placement of cards as a matrix
gameboard

## a simple visualization
image(gameboard, col=rainbow(12))
```

To arrange symbols or numbers on a grid graphically, one can directly work with the vector and use `%%` (modulo) and `%/%` (integer division) to calculate the coordinates:

```r
## arrange symbols or numbers at a grid
plot(NULL, xlim=c(0, 6), ylim=c(0, 4), axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
text(0.5 + (1:24 %% 6), 0.5 + (0:23 %/% 6), mixed)
box()
abline(h=seq(-0, 4), lty="dashed")
abline(v=seq(-0, 6), lty="dashed")
```

[image: Memory game]